# ¿Como se usa webpack js en un proyecto sin modulos js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

En un proyecto web antiguo que no se usan módulos javascript, sinó archivos .js con diversas functions que són referenciados desde index.html, ¿se puede usar webpack js para generar una versión destinada a producción con archivos js comprimidos, etc?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y se puede basar en opiniones. Intenta ser más específico y muestra detalles de lo que pretendes hacer y cuál sería la dificultad encontrada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

1 - mueves todos los archivos de tu proyecto a la carpeta src

2 - creas un archivo webpack.config.js en la raíz del proyecto

3 - Configuras el archivo webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CONFIG = {
    entry: 'index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
}
module.export = CONFIG;
```

4 - Instalas la dependencia

```
npm i webpack
```

5 - Editas el archivo package.json
agregas la directiva build en script

```
script: {
    build: 'node_modules/.bin/webpack'
}
```

6 - Ejecutar en el proyecto para compilar

```
npm run build
```